# Account for white space in capture group

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that captures the group security ID from Windows Down-Level format. It strips the domain part to only capture the ensuing ID after the "\"

Regex: `Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+.*?\\([^ ]+)`

```
Group:  Security ID:  CORP\VirtualUsers (match success)
```

However, if there is a space in the group name it does not match properly. It only matches on "VM"

```
Group:  Security ID:  CORP\VM Admins
```

How would I go about matching either scenario whether there is a space or not? Here is a link to my use case - https://regex101.com/r/gzFe0J/1

Comment: Use [`Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+[^\\]*\\(.+?)\s+Group Name:`](https://regex101.com/r/gzFe0J/2) if `Group Name:` always appears after that value.

Comment: See my answer below with a demo and a bit of explanation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - This works but I just realized that there may be a case where "Group Name:" does not come afterward. Some WIndows logging has "Account Name:" following. See [link](https://regex101.com/r/yuoAVu/1)

Comment: I added one more, simple, regex solution, and adjusted the initial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your ID value always appears before `Group Name:` or `Account Name:` add it as right-hand context and capture all between `Group:  Security ID: DOMAIN\` and `Group Name:` / `Account Name:`:

```
Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+[^\\]*\\(.+?)\s+(?:Group|Account)\s+Name:
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L30mbj/2). The `[^\\]*` will match zero or more chars other than `\` before a `\`, `\\` will match a `\` and `(.+?)` will capture any 1+ chars as few as possible up to the first `Group Name:` or `Account Name:`.

If your ID can only contain spaces that are enclosed with non-spaces, you need a simple `\S+(?: \S+)*` pattern, no need for a tempered greedy token with lookahead:

```
Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+[^\\]*\\(\S+(?: \S+)*)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L30mbj/3)

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/8o7Ueg):

```
String str = "<13>Jan 09 12:33:50 TESTSRV1 AgentDevice=WindowsLog    AgentLogFile=Security    PluginVersion=7.2.4.86    Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing    Computer=corp.devnet.com    OriginatingComputer=TESTSRV1    User=    Domain=    EventID=4755    EventIDCode=4755    EventType=8    EventCategory=13826    RecordNumber=1244048130    TimeGenerated=1483983229    TimeWritten=1483983229    Level=0    Keywords=0    Task=0    Opcode=0    Message=A security-enabled universal group was changed.  Subject:  Security ID:  CORP\\TESTUSR1  Account Name:  TESTUSR1  Account Domain:  CORP  Logon ID:  0x220f7a57  Group:  Security ID:  CORP\\Virtual Users  Group Name:  VirtualUsers  Group Domain:  CORP  Changed Attributes:  SAM Account Name: -  SID History:  -  Additional Information:  Privileges:  -";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("Group:\\s+Security\\s+ID:\\s+[^\\\\]*\\\\(.+?)\\s+(?:Account|Group)\\s+Name:");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: This works and I take it that it would be less resource intensive than using the greedy token with lookahead. Would you agree? This thread will give me a good base to study the different construct techniques. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You understand me right: a [tempered greedy token](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) is quite a resource consuming pattern. It should be unrolled to match faster. Using a quantified group is a less "expensive" way to match the strings you have.

Answer (score 2):

In Your case it seems like Group Name always appears after Group, If so:

Use

```
Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+.*?\\(.*)Group Name
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be:

```
Group:.+?\\\\((?:(?![ ]{2,}).)+)
```

See [**your modified example**](https://regex101.com/r/gzFe0J/3).

---

Explained (double backslashes are only need for `Java`):

```
Group:.+?\\\\         # looks for "Group:", anything lazily afterwards
                    # until a backslash
((?:(?![ ]{2,}).)+) # neg. lookahead, not two spaces consecutively
```

Comment: This appears to work in all 3 of my examples [link](https://regex101.com/r/msHctQ/1) - Further testing to be performed. I really need to study my Regex constructs to improve my skills. Thanks much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change your [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) from:
`Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+.*?\\([^ ]+)`
to:
`Group:\s+Security\s+ID:\s+.*?\\(\w+ ?\w+)`
That's it.

---

`(\w+ ?\w+)` it matches `one word` then a single optional `whitespace` and then the `second word` that you need.

---

> **your question** *How would I go about matching either scenario whether there is a space or not?*

With making the **match** as an **optional match** by `?`